# Concatenate 2 rows of the same dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, concatenation

Input:

```
  Name Surname
0 A    C     
1 B    D
```

Output required:

```
  Name Surname
0 A B    C D
```

Could not find any way to solve this. Is there any approach?

Comment: do you want to concat every 2 rows ? if so you can just do `df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg(' '.join)`

Comment: I want to concatenate the first 3 rows only. But I have 15 columns. Is there any approach?

Comment: quick and dirty but this should work `df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg(' '.join).head(1)` you should state your requirements more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: ' '.join(s)).to_frame().transpose()
  Name Surname
0  A B     C D
```

As suggested by [@Umar.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9375102/umar-h):

```
>>> df.agg(' '.join).to_frame().T
  Name Surname
0  A B     C D
```

*`T` is a property to `transpose` the dataframe.*

Comment: you can call `.agg` on the dataframe directly `df.agg(' '.join).to_frame().T`

Comment: Nice solution, +1 :)

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found